# NSFileProtectionComplete for iOS 4.0 apps

Tags: iphone, security, ios4, nsfilemanager

I saw a WWDC 2010 video about NSFileProtectionComplete and protecting app's data.

Are there any examples out there? Does any one have sample code to share?

Comment: You need to be careful with this. It's a good way to shoot yourself in the foot because the system can render the files unreadable at a time of it's choosing.

Comment: Documentation on that, TechZen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the NSFileManager class doc:

> The file is stored in an encrypted
>   format on disk and cannot be read from
>   or written to while the device is
>   locked or booting.

It's basically file vault for individual files. You just pass the constant when you set the file attributes.

> To mark a file as protected, you must
>   add an extended attribute to it. The
>   Foundation framework includes two ways
>   to add this attribute:
>
> When writing the contents of an NSData
>   object to disk using the
>   writeToFile:options:error: method,
>   include the
>   NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete
>   option.
>
> Use the
>   setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:
>   method of NSFileManager to add the
>   NSFileProtectionKey attribute (with
>   the NSFileProtectionComplete value) to
>   an existing file

.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html

Comment: Hey I am in a rush, so can you please explain me what NSFileProtetionKey does to the file actually??

Comment: If I set this behavior to Documents directory file.Is it possible to access the file on iDevice Locked State? @TechZen