# Protecting the app sandbox

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

So I am working on a test app that downloads files locally to the app file storage sandbox.  Some of these files may be sensitive and need to be protected.  My app has a login mechanism, so you wouldn't be able to access the files if you didn't have a login, so my main concern is the ability to sniff the contents (Perhaps on a jailbroken device??).

Now I was wondering if the best method to protecting these files is to encrypt each one independently?  Or perhaps there is a way to encrypt the whole sandbox?  Or is it encrypted by default?  Has anyone ever done anything like this before?

I apologize for the long string of questions, I am trying to gather as much info about this as possible before making a design decision...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to look into the [File Protection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW6) mechanisms in iOS 4 and later. That provides a way to mark a file as "protected" so it will be stored encrypted on disk at all times, only accessible when the device is unlocked (with a passcode).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217683/nsfileprotectioncomplete-for-ios-4-0-apps)

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting.  This may do what I want, but what about if the user does not have a password on the device?  Is there a way you could trigger the decryption when the user logged into the app??  I feel like that would be very useful...

Comment: No, you can't take advantage of Apple's scheme unless the user has a passcode on the device, because the passcode is a component of the encryption key used to protect the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the whole sandbox using the OS if you target iPhone 4 with OS 4.x. Even then, iOS has this concept of an 'escrow keychain' which is basically a cache of passwords and can he potentially hacked into. As far as I am aware, Mail is the only app that encrypts everything.

In order to encrypt your application data in this way, you just need to set the appropriate `NSFileProtectionKey` as documented in `NSFileManager`. But, as mentioned, this is not entirely secure.

You could try a custom category on the file manager that encrypts files based on your own requirement so that you have encrypted documents. The choice is yours.

Comment: That's sort of what I was thinking about trying.  Perhaps I will try the Apple methods first, and if that doesn't work, come up with my own schemes.