# iOS - Protecting files with a custom encryption key?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

Yesterday I posted this question about protecting files: [Protecting the app sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595955/protecting-the-app-sandbox)

As mentioned, it appears that this is effective for protecting a file if the user has a passcode on the iPad.  Naturally this raises the question of how to handle the encryption if the user does not.  Now I have an idea, but am not sure if it's feasible or not.

- Is there any way to override the encryption key to use a custom one?  My gut instinct is no, but I figured there may be a way.  (Btw, this is just an experiment for fun, I don't plan on submitting this to the app store...)  My application has a login, and it would be very handy if this could be handled at the application level to accommodate users that do not have a lock.

However, I suppose it wouldn't be unreasonable to disable the saving feature if there is no device passcode...  Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can generate encryption key, based on login/password, this allowing user to open his files only if he know password. However, you'll need provide ability to restore data in some way if user will forget his password.

Comment: Yeah, well I wanted to explore the options available before I go implementing my own encryption scheme.  I will ultimately do something like this if all else fails...

Comment: You can use OpenSSL, it contains all needed functionality.

Comment: Will this play nice while writing NSData to the disk?

Comment: openSSL should work with char*, however NSData can be easily converted to this type.

Comment: This is true, interesting approach.  Have you ever done this?  I am going to dig around some more (and wait to see if anyone else has anything to add), before I mark this...

Comment: Unfortunately, I only looked over OpenSSL sources some time ago, and know what it should be able to do.