# How do we secure the blob data in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, ipad, blob

How do we secure the blob data in iPhone? Can we use Keychain access or [data protection APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595955/protecting-the-app-sandbox)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keychain, or encrypt the blob.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Documentation : [Working with Protected Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW4)