# How to protect (encrypt) data stored by webkit/local store

Tags: ios, security, encryption, webkit, data-protection

I'm developing an app that uses the PhoneGap framework, and therefore is just a plain web-app that uses HTML5. As with many web-apps, my customer also wants data available when the device is offline. For those situations, I want to store data in the local store of the browser.

However, the customer also wants the data to be encrypted, so in case of a device loss no sensitive data gets into wrong hands. My current research brought up 2 *possible* approaches:

1) Encrypt any data using a JS encryption framework before storing in the local store. Since my app requires a user login, I could use the user password to derive encryption keys (user password is stored in the iOS keychain)

2) User iOS' data protection mechanisms https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

For 2), is it correct that enabling data protection in the developer portal (App IDs section) **does not** actually encrypt anything, but rather **enables the possibility** to encrypt specific files using the appropriate `NSData` or `NSFileManager` operations?
Or can the whole sandbox be encrypted (including browser local store!) by enabling data protection on the App ID/provisioning profile level?

Is there any other recommended approach to secure the stored data in the browser's local store?

Comment: Derive the key from the user's password (using a proper KDF and a salt). Require the user to enter the password when starting the application. But obviously that's only secure if the user's password is strong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option works cross-device.

Two solid JS Encryption frameworks I found in my research are

- [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/&ei=VoNmUcenD8e-PNG6gZAP&usg=AFQjCNGVUDT-vAAV8Ro1MZ-R4oBNY2AeSw&sig2=FoWQGGTVmn2cwEOhHJelHQ&bvm=bv.45107431,d.ZWU)
- [CryptoJS](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/&ei=CIRmUaGvBIXVPJLIgaAC&usg=AFQjCNHV-4a2QYiniWdW0kYuM_mwgRIeJw&sig2=wYV6GYhcriASo9bjFyIgJA&bvm=bv.45107431,d.ZWU) (faster than SJCL in my tests using AES-256)

Whatever you do, make sure the possible data used for deriving an encryption key (password in your example) is stored safely.

Comment: Using iOS' keychain should be safe, right? I found code examples that additionally encrypt passwords before storing in the keychain. Is this necessary? I thought the point of the keychain already *is* to have a secure location to store sensitive stuff ... ?

Also, can someone enlighten me on 2) above please?

Comment: Quoting the Mac Developer Library:
"A keychain is an encrypted container that holds passwords for multiple applications and secure services. Keychains are secure storage containers, which means that when the keychain is locked, no one can access its protected contents."

So there is no need to additionally encrypt passwords, unless you are very paranoid ;)

source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9

Comment: Ah thanks for the info. 2) is still unclear to me however. Can the app sandbox be globally encryptet (inkl. browser local store) by enabling data protection in the provisioning profile?

Comment: I see, take a look at this question, as it addresses some of your concerns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595955/protecting-the-app-sandbox

Comment: Unfortunately this page does not explain what the provisioning profile option does.