# Password protecting files in NSDocumentsDirectory

Tags: ios, nsdocumentdirectory, ios-enterprise

Hi I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175846/encrypting-or-protecting-files-stored-in-ios-apps-nsdocumentsdirectory) earlier and could not get a perfect answer for it.

So let me ask this question once more, I have a requirement where I will be password protecting all my files in the NSDocumentsDirectory with a key that will be **pushed from a server every day**. What is the best way to do it **without taking a hit on performance**.

I would also be doing the key **refresh whenever a key expires** and I should **re-encrypt or re-protect all my files in the directory**. I would be storing the key from server using iOS keychain.

I tried NSFileManager's File Protection Values but I could not use my own key there.

I saw all this

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

[What are the new "iOS data protection APIs"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081102/what-are-the-new-ios-data-protection-apis)

[What are the new "iOS data protection APIs"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081102/what-are-the-new-ios-data-protection-apis)

[Secure contents in Documents directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471270/secure-contents-in-document-directory)

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html

http://pastie.org/426530

[NSFileProtectionComplete for iOS 4.0 apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217683/nsfileprotectioncomplete-for-ios-4-0-apps)

and did not know how to proceed. So please guys any help would be of great use. Any sample or good way to implement or any one has done something like this before.

Thanks a ton, in advance.